# How to implement T for binding JSON in Flutter model?

Tags: json, binding, dart, flutter, generic-programming

I want to use Generic Type Parameter in Flutter, but I'm confused on how to use it with my JSON. Here's the code I've tried:

```
class BaseMdl {
    bool status;
    int http_code;
    String message;
    dynamic data;

    BaseMdl({this.status, this.http_code, this.message, List<dynamic> data}) : data = data ?? <dynamic>[];

    factory BaseMdl.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
        var list = parsedJson['data'] as List;
        List<dynamic> dataList = list.map((i) => BaseMdl.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return BaseMdl(
        status: parsedJson['status'],
        http_code: parsedJson['http_code'],
        message: parsedJson['message'],
        data: dataList
        );
    }
}
```

Sorry I'm a beginner in Flutter.

Comment: What is T?  Do you mean T as in Generic Type Parameter T?

Comment: I already edit my question @RobertHarvey , maybe it helps :)

Comment: That's a Generic Type Parameter.

Comment: See here: http://thetechnocafe.com/just-enough-dart-for-flutter-tutorial-03-classes-and-generics/

Comment: have a look here https://news.dartlang.org/2016/12/dart-121-generic-method-syntax.html